# How is This Substitution Made in the Langrangian Derivation?

Tags: calculus, vectors, substitution

The following is taken from a wiki article on Brilliant - web address: https://brilliant.org/wiki/lagrangian-formulation-of-mechanics/

The article is on the Langrangian and its derivation. During the derivation the following equation is given as a statement of D'Alambert's principle:

$$\vec{F}_{\text{net}} \cdot \delta \vec{r} = m \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}\cdot \delta \vec{r}$$

After which the following equation is used: $(xy)' = x'y + xy'$ to rewrite the right hand side so that:

$$m \frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}\cdot \delta \vec{r} = m \left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\cdot\delta\vec{r}\right) - \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d\delta\vec{r}}{dt}\right] $$

What is $x$, what is $y$ and how is the equation applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are some functions of variable $t$. The derivative is with respect to this variable, so $x'$ is equivalent to $\frac{dx}{dt}$. The formula for $(xy)'$ is the derivative of a product of functions. In this case they use $$x=\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$$ and $$y=\delta\vec r$$
Then $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\delta\vec r\right)=\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right)\delta\vec r+\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}\delta\vec r$$
They just move the last term to the other side

Comment: I take it that means a dot product between two vectors can be treated just like $f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: Yes. In reality each component of the vector is a function say of $t$, so you would have $f_x(t)g_x(t)+f_y(t)g_y(t)+f_z(t)g_z(t)$

Answer (score 1):

$$(xy)'=x'y+xy'$$
is just the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) in lagrangian notation, and can be used here as $x,y$ are both functions of $t$,time